# why I can not link these two pages in my django project

Tags: python, html, django

I have 2 models named "developer" and "skill". I made a page for all the developers that have their respective information. Now, I want to make a page that lists all the developers with links that navigate to their respective information page.

The page that shows all the developers' URLs is 'developers/' and its name is "developers". The URL of the second page is 'developers/id' and its name is developer, however it instead navigates to 'developers/developers/id'.

I tried the page that shows the information of a certain developer and it was ok but I have problem with this one cause it won't navigate.

here are my codes :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Developer, Skill


# Create your views here.

def show_developers(request):
    query = Developer.objects.all()
    context = {'devs': query}

    return render(request, 'users/devs.html', context=context)


def show_single_developer(request, pk):
    query = Developer.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'dev': query}

    return render(request, 'users/single_dev.html', context=context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Skill(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('Beginner', 'Beginner'),
        ('Junior', 'Junior'),
        ('Senior', 'Senior'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=10)


class Developer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    skills = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import show_developers, show_single_developer

urlpatterns = [
    path('developers/', show_developers, name='developers'),
    path('developers/<str:pk>/', show_single_developer, name='developer'),
]
```

devs.html

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>FullName</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>details</th>
    </tr>
    {% for dev in devs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{dev.full_name}}</td>
            <td>{{dev.username}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'developer' dev.id %}">View</a></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

single_dev.html

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}

<h2>{{dev.full_name}}</h2>
<hr>
<h3>Intro</h3>
<h4>{{dev.intro}}</h4>

{% for skill in dev.sills.all %}
    <div>
        <p>{{skill.name}}</p>
        <p>{{skill.level}}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}


{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

TraceBack Section
[image]

and I add the structures of this app too

[image]

Error page
[image]

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: apart from error trace back, there is an extra ' in  href attribute of devs.html

Comment: I removed that extra ' in my code but that was not the problem :(((

Comment: I add the error message in the post and also the traceback section